# Changing class of element in jQuery and applying actions to new class

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create different animated mouse overs for menu items when they are selected. I'm working out the code for the first section (work) and have programmed in the first mouse over and an on click function to change it's class from .menu to .selected. When I click, I can see in "inspect element" that the class for the element has indeed changed but the mouse over is acts as if it were .menu class.

HTML:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="menu"><div id="work">WORK</div></li>
            <li class="menu">CAREER</li>
            <li class="menu">CONTACT</li>
            <li class="menu">ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menu").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#553579"
        }, 100 )
    });
$(".menu").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#717171"
        }, 100 )
    });

$(".selected").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#553579"
        }, 100 )
    });
$(".selected").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        color: "#FFFFFF"
        }, 100 )
    });

$("#work").on("click", function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("menu");
    $(this).parent().addClass("selected");

    $(this).animate({
        right: "-20px",
        }, 500 );
    $(this).parent().animate({
        color: "FFFFFF"
        }, 500)

    $(".display").load("work.html");

});
})
```

As you can see, on click, the element also moves 20 px and animates to change to #FFFFFF but as soon as mouse leaves, it turns back to #717171 and the initial mouseover is applied even though the class has indeed been changed to .selected.

I am using jquery-2.1.4.min.js and jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js